# When will muscle be cannibalized?

Tags: muscle

Can you tell me what are all the cases when muscle would be cannibalized? I've heard the two following cases will cannibalize muscle, but I still don't quite understand.

### Aerobic Exercise

Arnold Schwarzenegger says in *[The New Ecyclopedia of Modern Bodybuilding](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684857219)*:

> Too much aerobics also encourages the
> body to metabolize lean body mass --
> muscle -- to create additional energy.
> The body can actually cannibalize
> muscle tissue, especially white fiber
> "power" muscle in order to fuel
> aerobic exercise.

Why would the human body evolve to cannibalize muscle during cardio? Why not just take energy from the food in your stomach (granted that you do have leftover food)?

### Skinny People

[Scooby from Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi-jnsG0Z7Y) says that the body's energy stores are three tiered - Food > Fat > Muscle. If energy can not be obtained from one tier, the body seeks the next tier. Since muscle is the last tier, and virtually everyone has some amount of fat, how is the muscle tier ever reached? I suppose the muscle tier will be reached for anorexic people, how about for everyone else?

### High Intensity Training

Jamez said this in an [article on optimal rep range](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/topicoftheweek8.htm):

> Remember the muscle-building process
> described in Grow Baby, Grow?
> Microtrauma stimulates increased
> protein synthesis, and muscle growth
> is positively affected by a number of
> hormones that are released after
> weight training. High volume, multiple
> set programs cause more microtrauma
> and greater hormone secretion-so the
> end result is more muscle!
>
> This probably explains why I was
> unimpressed with HIT. Although HIT
> uses high reps, you only perform one
> "hardcore" set per bodypart. I
> actually lost muscle and began to feel
> like I didn't even train!

His train of logic isn't so clear. What about HIT causes muscle loss?

Comment: I don't think the right term is cannibalized @JoJo ;-)

Comment: It's not the traditional sense of cannibalization, but this term was borrowed to describe this effect. I've heard it used in many places. Heck, Arnold himself used it.

Comment: A more nuanced description than "cannibalize" is that muscle rebuilding rate decreases. Every process in the body is dynamic equilibrium, including tissue damage and cell death. Muscles break down all the time on the micro level, and they get repaired depending on the NEED (ie, are they used a lot) and the RESOURCES (ie, do you have the amino acids available, after repairing vital organs etc.).

Comment: Your questions are so great, JoJo. I don't have time to answer this one now, but if no one else answers it in the next day or so, I can shed some light on this topic for you :) p.s. Is your avatar a photo of you? Do you compete?

Comment: @Barbie No, that's not me. That's my #1 inspiration Andressa Vieira. Perfect proportions!

Comment: "Catobolism" is a term that loosely describes the mechanism that breaks down muscle tissue. Based on this, I think it's not inconceivable that someone might mistakenly use the term "Cannibalize" instead of "Catabolize". That being said, "cannibalism" does seem to be an adequate description of what's happening inside.

Comment: As an old time bodybuilder, I'd like to offer a "trick" we used to use to determine if glycogen stores are depleted and thus approaching the "catabolism" threshold. [Ketosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketosis) is a state of the body that indicates you are glycogen depleted.  To test for Ketosis, many drug stores sell otc Ketostix to test for ketones in the urine.  This is a great way to determine the existence of carbs in your system.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**To make a long story short**: you will start burning muscle when you run out of carbs and dietary protein. Also, your body will only keep as much protein in the muscles as it has to: if you're not training in a way that requires a muscle to maintain it's size, the body will leech out some of its protein and use it for something else. If you want more details, here's the long story.

**Background.** To understand why protein is drawn from the muscles to be used as energy, you have to understand a little bit about how energy is made in the body (metabolism). In order for fat or carbs (or protein, as a last resort) to be fully converted into energy (i.e. burned), they have to go through a process called the [citric acid cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle), which releases energy through a number of reactions. This is the predominant energy system at rest and during prolonged aerobic exercise, and the primary source of energy in these states is usually fat. But here's the thing: one of the intermediary products of the citric acid cycle (oxaloacetate) requires a derivative from either carbs or protein. Because of this, to metabolize fat, you have to break down at least some carbs or protein. A common summary of this is "at burns in a flame of carbohydrates." Your body prefers to burn carbs over protein, but it has limited carb stores. If it runs out of those, it will start breaking down protein (into [ketone bodies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_bodies)) to be used as fuel. This is also important for fueling your brain once you run out of carbs, since it can only use carbs or ketone bodies as fuel (not fat). It kind of makes sense that your body would evolve the ability to use protein for energy as a back-up energy source considering there's so much of it in your body.

**Aerobic Exercise.** Prolonged cardio can deplete your carb stores (colloquially known as "[hitting the wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_the_wall)"). For example, if you do a marathon without carb-loading in the days before the event and without consuming carbs during the race, you will run out of carbs in your body and start burning protein. According to the "hitting the wall" article on Wikipedia, carb stores can come depleted in under two hours of moderate exercise. The harder you work out, the faster you'll deplete your stores, because as you work out harder, you begin to burn a larger proportion of your energy as carbs instead of fat.

It makes sense that you would burn protein that you recently ate first, but even if that's all you burn, now you don't have that protein around to help you *build* muscle (not to mention all the other stuff in your body). Also, if you don't have an immediate use for protein, your body converts it irreversibly into fat (i.e. your body can't convert fat back into protein), so depending on when you ate, you may not have as much protein available as you think.

**Food > Fat > Muscle.** This is hard to discuss in detail, because it's an oversimplification, but I can at least comment on the spirit of it. During starvation (or dieting) muscle is preserved as much as possible, but based on the info above you can see how this hierarchy wouldn't always apply; there are some things protein can be used for that fat can't be.

**High Intensity Training.** I'm not very familiar with weight training HIT, but I get the author's logic. As I understand it, HIT is when you do one high-rep set to exhaustion (per muscle group). However, according to the author, doing *multiple* sets is more beneficial for muscle growth. I assume this is because HIT doesn't overload the muscles in the right way (there are a few different ways to overload the muscles that all correspond to different goals. Check out this [ACSM position stand](http://journals.lww.com/acsm-msse/Fulltext/2009/03000/Progression_Models_in_Resistance_Training_for.26.aspx) if you want to know more). Your body doesn't waste resources making a muscle any bigger than it has to be. If you don't constantly require your muscle to be big/strong (by doing the right type of training), your body will take unneeded protein from the muscle and use it for something else.

Comment: Some people say that muscles are used before fat....http://www.quora.com/Does-the-body-burn-fat-before-it-burns-muscle-for-energy so during cardio if you use up all the carbs, you start using your muscles for energy.

Comment: I did.not.knew.protein.became.fat that easily. This mean that to get strong I must do exercise, and then eat protein during repair phase?

Comment: Getting strong does require exercise, though after you're exercise or repair phase you should just have small sugary drink to replenish your glucose level, with a balanced diet.

Comment: Could you explain why carbs or protein are required to metabolize fat? I'm no expert in the citric acid cycle but my understanding is that it's fed with Acetyl CoA which can be produced from fatty acids?

Answer (score 1):

First off, human metabolism isn't remotely the same as birds.  Bird migration is similar to HIT. HIT **does** metabolize (or cannibalize) muscle mass.  I've seen it in wrestlers for years.  Wrestler workouts are the most intense training out there.  Average workouts are HIT training sessions.  And every year, my football players who turn out for wrestling get really frustrated when they see their lift maxes (strength) go down.  BUT one thing I noticed is these athlete's strength spring back at a super high-rate.  They will spend all spring and summer working on building their mass and then try to maintain this mass during the season only to lose substantial amounts during their wrestling season.  Wrestlers call this "hardening" up.

Extended HIT training will cannibalize muscle mass.  Long anaerobic workouts (low impact) as well as balanced dieting is how you metabolize fat.  It's a long, arduous task.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer it in simpler terms.**It is easier for your body to store energy in the form of fat rather than muscles as it takes less amount of energy for your body to form fat rather than muscles. So , muscles are bigger source of energy for your body than fat**. Said that , when the body senses that it requires more energy , in situations of long period of cardio or weight lifting which cannot be fulfilled by fat as source, it starts using your muscles for its energy requirement rather than fat.